# How to encode categorical Variables to pass to SVM

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm, categorical-data

I am doing some NLP tasks. A feature in my list is the POS tag of a sentence. How can i pass the POS tags as a feature to SVM as it expects numerical data.

Comment: What NLP task are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Map/Dictionary to convert each POS Tag to Number.

List all POS Tags and assign particular Number to it.
For Example,

```
NN -> 1
JJ -> 2
VB -> 3
DT -> 4
...
...
```

Whenever you encounter a particular POS, change it to its corresponding number.

Comment: Any basis for this ?

Comment: It's one of the standard process followed by many researchers. You can find multiple papers where conversion is done this way.

Comment: Think in a naive way, What is POS? It represents some information about token. NN, JJ,.. is just a representation. Instead of NN, JJ, VB, DT,... we are using 1, 2, 3, 4,... as representation.

Comment: But  3>2 for SVM and J JJ and VB have no such relation

Comment: It may not have issue, as in your training data, kernel will not find direct relation between 2 & 3. It will be able to learn that there is no direct relation between 2 & 3 for prediction. One way to order this number is based on word order preference/similarity like, NN NNS NNP NNPS can be kept in same order, VB VBD VBG, ... can be kept in same order. You can use same order as - https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html. What NLP task are you working on??